# Update select list depending on another list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking around here for a time now, but I didn't really found what I'm needing.

I've a dropdown with some teachers in it. The second list should contain the courses he/she teaches.

So, a little example:

Mr X teaches maths and biology.
Mrs Y teaches maths

If X is selected in the first list, the second list should contain maths and biology. If Y is selected, the list should only contain maths.

The PHP part, HTML, CSS, is not the issue, it's only about the 'refreshing/updating' of the second list.

```
<select name="lecturer_id" id="lecturer_id">
    <option value="22">X</option>
    <option value="30">Y</option>
</select>
```

I'm looking for a very simple solution, because my knowledge of javascript is poor. So that's why I prefer a jQuery solution.

--
update

The data is comming from a database. My application currently generates the follow HTML:
http://pastebin.com/9rEWKAkF

The two lists, lecturer_id and coure_id are dynamicly generatrd with the information in my database. The list I want to update is the second one, course_id. I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: 1) Have you tried any JS? 2) Where will the list of courses for each teacher come from? Hard-coded? A request to the server?

Comment: What have you tried?  How are you going to filter the list of course to just the ones taught by a teacher?  Where is that data?  Your question is far too broad and contains too many unknowns.

Comment: "What have you tried?" He said his knowledge was poor, so assume he simply doesn't know. The question is clear and concise. IMO, I don't understand the downvotes. We all started somewhere, don't be so stuck up.

Comment: On what basis do you close this question as "Not a real question", really? Granted it *could* need some more details, but they are superfluous. What is being asked here is simple and definitely *not* ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple, attach to first selector change event handler, which will update other selector.

HTML:

```
<select name="lecturer_id" id="lecturer_id">
    <option value="22">X</option>
    <option value="30">Y</option>
</select>
<select name="discipline" id="discipline">
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JS:

```
var teachers = {
    22: ['math', 'biology'],
    30: ['math']
}
var dis_update = function() {

    var lecturer_id = $('#lecturer_id option:selected').val();
    var dis = $('#discipline').empty();
    for (i in teachers[lecturer_id]) {
        var d_name = teachers[lecturer_id][i];
        dis.append($('<option>').val(d_name).text(d_name));
    }
}
$('#lecturer_id').change(dis_update);
dis_update();​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/2vgpj/)

Comment: I would also like to thank you. See my comment above please :-)

Answer (score 3):

Well I don't know how you gonna have the data for your select boxes but I will give you some code for your startup. I coded it as simple as possible so you can understand it

```
//here is your sample data array
var data = {"X":['maths','bio'], 
        "Y":['maths']};

//the event listener for lecturer selectbox that will listen for selection changes
$('#lecturer_id').change(function(){ 

//gets the value of the lecturer select box
var selecti = $('#lecturer_id >option:selected').text();
      //ensure to empty the other select box for subjects
      $('#teaches').empty();
      var i = 0 ;
      //append the subjects of the lecturer on the other select box
      for(i = 0; i < data[selecti].length; i++){
             //add an option element for every item
         $("#teaches").append('<option>' + data[selecti][i]  +'</option>');
      } 
});
```

A demo for your disposal
http://jsfiddle.net/nCA9u/

Comment: Thanks for the information, my data is in a database. For each teacher I've a record with his user_id and his name. For a course, actually the same: and id and a name.

I tried your example, but I'm not really having succes. I suppose this code should be added at the bottom of the page, right?

To make it more clear, I've uploaded the HTML-code generated by my application right now: http://pastebin.com/9rEWKAkF

(so the list with course_id should be updated dynamicly)

Comment: well did you saw my fiddle? I think the javascript code in the fiddle must work anywhere in your codes, just include the `$(document).ready*()`

Comment: That's what I tought as well, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on my code...

Comment: Got it working, I loaded it wrong. The data is in JSON format, right? So I suppose I could create that output with PHP?